# auto generate hash equals for many classes

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, hashcode

I have many classes more then 500. I have to generate hash equals for every classes. Is there a way to generate it by once? Not clicking right->source->generate hash... for every single class.

Greets Benjamin

Comment: might be, but don't expect it to follow your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You may try Googles Autovalue: https://github.com/google/auto/
Or Immutables: http://immutables.github.io/